# python/matplotlib - Specifying Parasite Axis Length

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I am plotting data from several sources and need [multiple x axes](http://uairp.wff.nasa.gov/browse/file/ozone/natal/2011/nat20110526-1519.html), preferably offset such as those seen in the link. I would very much like my x axes to have variable length, allowing me to put many plots on the same figure.  What I have done so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes,yscale='log')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

par1 = host.twiny()

offset = 60

new_fixed_axis = par1.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par1.axis['bottom'] = new_fixed_axis(loc='bottom',
                                     axes=par1,
                                     offset=(0, -60))

host.set_xlim(200, 350)
host.set_ylim(1050, 100)
par1.set_xlim(0, 1)

host.set_xlabel('Temperature (K)')
host.set_ylabel('Pressure (hPa)')
par1.set_xlabel('Relative Humidity (%)')

p1, = host.plot(T,P)
p2, = host.plot(pT,P)
p2, = par1.plot(RH,P)
```

So I get the axis to drop down, but cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to get the axis to actually compress horizontally (e.g. like the blue axes in the linked figure above).

My question is how can this be done (if at all)?

---

@Oz123

Here is what I have:

```
host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes,yscale='log')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

par1 = host.twiny()

new_fixed_axis = par1.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis

cax1 = plt.axes(axisbg='none',frameon=False)
cax1 = plt.add_axes(plt.get_position(), frameon=False)
par1.axis['bottom'] = new_fixed_axis(loc='bottom',
                                     axes=cax1,
                                     offset=(0, -60))
```

When I get to:

```
cax1 = plt.add_axes(plt.get_position(), frameon=False)
```

My previous x/y axes disappear, and I am left with a grey screen with only cax1.

My apologies, I'm just picking up matplotlib so I'M afraid I'm still quite a novice here.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `par1.axis['bottom']` with the major `ax`object, so you are quite limited in what you can actually do.
Instead you should create 2 or more `axes` instances. And put them on the figure instance.

## adding new axes instance

cax1 = plt.axes(axisbg='none', frameon=False)

Like this you could you have fine grain control of the size of your humidity scale.

The following line:

```
par1.axis['bottom'] = new_fixed_axis(loc='bottom',
                                     axes=par1,
                                     offset=(0, -60))
```

should be for example:

```
par1.axis['bottom'] = new_fixed_axis(loc='bottom',
                                     axes=cax1, # custom axis number 1
                                     offset=(0, -60))
```

Note that using [IPython](http://ipython.org), you can quickly find which methods are available to control
your newly created axes instance.

```
In [38]: cax1.set_ #tab pressed
cax1.set_adjustable            cax1.set_axis_bgcolor          cax1.set_frame_on              cax1.set_subplotspec           cax1.set_xticks
cax1.set_agg_filter            cax1.set_axis_off              cax1.set_gid                   cax1.set_title                 cax1.set_ybound
cax1.set_alpha                 cax1.set_axis_on               
# many more options trimmed, but I think you might want to take a look in:
```

## controlling the location of your newly created instance:

```
In [38]: cax1.set_position?
Type:       instancemethod
String Form:<bound method AxesSubplot.set_position of <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x2d7fb90>>
File:       /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py
Definition: cax1.set_position(self, pos, which='both')
Docstring:
Set the axes position with::

  pos = [left, bottom, width, height]
```